# ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous

Tags: c++

I am getting the error:

ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:

Distribution.H:515: note: candidate 1: Probability Normal::cdf(float64_t) const

Distribution.H:512: note: candidate 2: Probability Normal::cdf(const RationalVector&)"

RationalVector is defined as

```
class RationalVector : public Array<float64_t>
```

I am not able to change this class or the 'cdf' functions, as they are part of a third-party library. My code is giving the error for the following line:

```
return cABS*( exp(Md + 0.5*Vd)*stdN.cdf(d1) - K*stdN.cdf(d2) );
```

Where d1 and d2 are both doubles. I have tried casting both of them to float64_t to force the use of the first cdf function as such:

```
return cABS*( exp(Md + 0.5*Vd)*stdN.cdf((float64_t)d1) - K*stdN.cdf((float64_t)d2) );
```

However, the error still persists.

The Normal functions are defined as:

```
Probability cdf(float64_t x) const;
Probability cdf(RationalVector const & x);
```

Any ideas as to what the issue is, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second overload misses `const`, this may be the reason for ambiguity.

Try making `stdN` a const object if you intend to invoke the first overload.